# How to install kernel sources

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, angstrom

I 'm running Angstrom distribution (console only) on BeagleBoard-xM. Image was build on [Narcissus](http://narcissus.angstrom-distribution.org/), with Bootloader Files (x-load/u-boot/scripts) added.

I noticed that `usr/src` directory is empty. I intend to install kernel source packages. For this reason, I downloaded Linux kernel 2.6.32 from https://www.kernel.org. What should be my next steps? I 've been searching for days, but I didn't find anything.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Err... you sure your distribution doesn't include a package manager that do that for you? look for linux-source or linux-src package. BTW, don't use 2.6!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just untar (`tar xf kernel-sources.tar.whatever`) it into `/usr/src` - or anywhere else for that matter.

Just remember that if you want to use the symlinks `/lib/modules/kernel/{build,source}` that point to the kernel build and source tree, respectively, as created by `make modules_install`, you'll need to either keep the sources at the same place, or update the symlinks accordingly.

That said, if you are planning anything else than just one-off kernel compilation, clone [Linus'](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/) or [any other git tree](https://git.kernel.org) and use that instead of the tarballs. It can be interesting even for "just" configuring the kernel, since you can get `.config` versioning for free.

Comment: The command is `tar` not `tax`